# JAXB how to map composite key fields as siblings

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jaxb

I have the following entities defined after my database model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long personId;
    private String personName;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="children")
    @XmlElement(name="child")
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>(0);

    // getters & setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
@XmlRootElement(name = "child")
public class Child implements java.io.Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildId id;
    private Date childName;

    // getters & setters
}

@Embeddable
public class ChildId implements java.io.Serializable {
    @XmlTransient
    private Person parentId;
    private Date childBirthDate;
    private int childOrder;

    // getters & setters
}
```

In the current state of thing, when marshalling using JAXB here is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
    <personId>7</personId>
    <personName>Foo</personName>
    <children>
        <child>
            <childName>Bar</childName>
            <id>
                <childBirthDate>2001-06-22</childBirthDate>
                <childOrder>1</childOrder>
            </id>
        </child>
    </children>
</person>
```

What I would like to get instead is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
    <personId>7</personId>
    <personName>Foo</personName>
    <children>
        <child>
            <childName>Bar</childName>
            <childBirthDate>2001-06-22</childBirthDate>
            <childOrder>1</childOrder>
        </child>
    </children>
</person>
```

Is there a way for me to get the ChildId's fields to the same level as the other Child's fields?

Please advise what my options are.

Comment: Move the fields from your `ChildId` to `Child` class. That way they would all show up on the same level. Then you simply need to annotate every field with `@Id` to have the same effect as with `@EmbeddedId`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I went through many documents and never saw it was possible to have several `@Id` annotations in the same class. So, thank you very much as it's working well ;) Can you post this as an answer so i can mark the topic as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving comment to answer:

As multiple `@Id`s are possible in the same class, you could simply move the fields from the `ChildId` class into the `Child` class. Then you annotate each field with `@Id` (the fields which were moved from `ChildId`). This way you have all fields on the same level as they are in the same class, while also retaining the functionality of `@EmbeddedId`